# PHP CRUD with MySQL on two Files

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am very New with php and Database...

I have a File where Display the Comment, **contact.php** , [here](https://codepen.io/mezb/pen/WBEEEQ) to schow it and my Css, because **codepen** have only for JS , the Comment form not to Display , the Code for Comment to be call **classprove.php** it have in PHP and it is [here](https://codeshare.io/Gq9byk) , people help me, for build these Code...

Than have the File **kommenter_verwalter.php** where i will to Display my Comments output on Tabelle .

So , i have Two Files for my Comments , **classprove.php** for Administrate my Comments , and **kommenter_verwalter.php** , where i will they to Display.

I to try with these Code to build a File for delete with a button beside each row so that if I want to delete that row I click the delete button .

**Edit new my Code**

Now to search my Code **without** connect to my **classprove.php** File .

The Code from **kommenter_verwalter.php**,

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);



class ClassProveContakt2 
{


          private $dbHost = 'localhost'; # Host der Datenbank
          private $dbName = 'meine';      # Name der Datenbank
          private $dbUser = 'root';      # Name phpmyadmin
          private $dbPass = 'pass';      # Passwort


          private $name;
          private $email;
          private $message;
          private $datetime;
          private $ip;
          private $db;
          private $connection; 
          private $id;
          private $sql; 
          private $statement;
          private $success;     




          function CommentToDatabase()
          {
              // Establish connection with MYSQL Server
            try
            {
              $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=meine", "root", "pass");
            }
             catch (PDOException $pe)
            {
               echo "<br>Cannot connect to database: " . $pe->getMessage();
                return false;
            }

            if(isset($_POST["delete"])) {
             try {


                   $connection = new PDO($id, $name, $email, $message, $datetime, $ip);

                   $id = $_POST["id"];

                   $sql = "DELETE FROM mela WHERE id = :id";

                   $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
                   $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
                   $statement->execute();

                   $success = "User successfully deleted";
                  }catch(PDOException $error) {
                        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
                   }

             } 
           }
           function tabelle() 
           {
              $db = $this ->CommentToDatabase();

              if ($db) 
              {  

                 echo "<table id='user' class='table table-bordered'>

                    <tr>
                      <th>id</th>
                      <th>name</th>
                      <th>email</th>
                      <th>message</th>
                      <th>datetime</th>
                      <th>ip</th>
                       <th>Delete User</th>
                      </tr>";

                     foreach ($db as $row){

                        echo <<<EOT
                           <tr>
                              <td>{$row['id']}</td>
                              <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                              <td>{$row['email']}</td>
                              <td>{$row['message']}</td>
                              <td>{$row['datetime']}</td>
                              <td>{$row['ip']}</td>
                              <td><button type "submit" name="delete" value="{$row['id']}">löschen</button> 
                            </tr>

EOT;
                     }

                    echo "</table>";   


                 }

           }
}

$News = new ClassProveContakt2;
$News -> CommentToDatabase();
$News -> tabelle();
?>
```

When write `sudo tail -n0 -f /var/log/apache2/error.log /var/log/mysql/error.log`

Now to come not error , but nothing Display...

I to observe that i have not,

> $_POST["delete"]

and

> $_POST["id"];

I to build my **form** with only (name, email and message) , **id** have with phpmyadmin to build . . These piece Code have in internet to found...

Can Please anyone tell me , how can to change these part the Code .

How to [show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0kMS.png) my Tabelle on phpmyadmin ,

I to want that the the File **kommenter_verwalter.php** (there which here give) , the output Display **only** the comments(name, email , message,..) on a Table whith the **button** , **delete** as this Screeshot to [show](https://codeshare.io/Gq9byk)...,and the File **classprove.php** to stay as Administrate for Comment .

Can Please anyone help me with this Problem , Thanks !

Comment: you have function `ShowForm()` but you have call your function by wrong name  `s` i.e : `$Newobjects -> ShowForms();`. maybe this might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! , but edit new my function from  function ShowForm to  function ShowForms , and to come these warning too...

Comment: put your `<form>` around `echo '<form>...</form>';`

Comment: Thanks for you recomendation , but i will not display my form on these File , i have another File that does it... , when you will , can it here to show , i to want the Tabel from these File to show...

Comment: Now to come ,  Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /var/www/html/kommenter_verwalter.php on line 34

Comment: Where is this line ..? Can you update your post with changes made till now ..?

Comment: yes , i does it , the Line 34 is ,  <form method="POST" action="classprove.php">

Comment: Do like this —> `echo '<form method="POST" action="classprove.php"> .. </form>';`

Comment: Very Thanks , now not to come these Warning , these , unexpected 'if' (T_IF), Line 62, on ;  if(isset($_POST["delete"])) {

Comment: Yes these error are because you cannot directly put your `if statement` in classes put them inside `function`.

Comment: thanks, i does it, now to come , Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$row' expecting ',' or ';' , i to change from "<td>" $row["id"]"</td>" to "<td>" $row["id"];"</td>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because are People on **stackoverflow** which not to let my [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56304270/how-to-use-crud-on-sql) Question to answer ,they to hiding it.....Titel name from it "How to use CRUD on SQL" , and because it is very similar as these , i answer here ....

Now can Display the File **kommenter_verwalter.php**  without connect to my **classprove.php** File .

I has some mistakes therefore can't Display it....

How have now my **kommenter_verwalter.php**,

```
class ClassProveContakt2 
{  

      private $conn;



   function __construct() {

      $dbHost = 'localhost'; # Host der Datenbank
      $dbName = 'meine';      # Name der Datenbank
      $dbUser = 'root';      # Name der Datenbank
      $dbPass = 'pass';      # Passwort

      // declare the object conn, which conect to the Datebase .

          $this->conn = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPass,$dbName);  
    }
     // mit these function delete the Comment .

    function deleteComment($id){

      /* build a Variable to delete the Comment ,on **id=?** , give **?**  
       because i will the Comment to delete on hand (with the Bottom "delete")
       give not Value to **id**  , the **?** . */

      $sql = "DELETE FROM mela WHERE id=?";

       // prepare and bind the connection to Database .

       $statement= $this->conn->prepare($sql);
       $statement -> bind_param('i',$id);
       $statement->execute();
    }  
    function printAdminTable() {

        //connect to the Table , name "mela" and the Rows which are in it .  

         $sql = "SELECT id, name, email, message, datetime,ip FROM mela ORDER BY datetime DESC";

       // prepare and bind the connection to the Table . 

       $statement= $this->conn->prepare($sql);
       $statement->execute();

       $result = $statement-> get_result();

         //On *if* Statement asked if all is ok on the connection with sql
        // when yes ,build the Table .

       if ( $result ) {
            echo "
        <form action=\"prove_comment.php\" method=\"POST\">\n
        <table id='user' class='table table-bordered' border= '1px solid';>
                <tr>
                 <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>E-mail</th>
                  <th>Message</th>
                  <th>Datetime</th>
                  <th>IP</th>
                   <th>Delete</th>
                  </tr>";

              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

                echo <<<EOT
                  <tr>
                      <td>{$row['id']}</td>
                      <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                      <td>{$row['email']}</td>
                      <td>{$row['message']}</td>    
                      <td>{$row['datetime']}</td>
                      <td>{$row['ip']}</td>
                      <td><button type="submit" name="delete" value="{$row['id']}">löschen</button>
                  </tr>

EOT;
              }
             echo '</table></form>';  
            // when not connection on sql .
            } else {
          echo '<p class="error">Hm. $arrRows enthält nichts oder false. '
            .'Entweder ist die Datenbank noch leer oder da ist was falsch.</p>';
     }            
    }
        // connection to sql closse .
     function __destruct(){
       $this->conn->close();    
     }
    }   // Build the call to the method .
    $News = new ClassProveContakt2();
       /* Because befor have add 'delete' on my POST Method                         
        (Linne 77 ,  "<td><button type="....) , with the **if** Statement asked if
        it is , when yes , delete it . */     
    if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $News -> deleteComment($_POST['delete']);
    }
    $News -> printAdminTable();
```

Screehot how to show now my File **kommenter_verwalter.php** , [how to show it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T55Ub.png)

Answer (score 0):

Above error indicate that there is error in `'` and  `"` you have not place them properly that's why `complier` is not able to `parse` that part of your code. Change that line like below this should work  :

```
 echo "<form action='classprove.php' method='post'>
              <tr>
               <td> '".$row["id"]."'</td>
                <td>'". $row["name"]."'</td>
                <td>'". $row["email"]."'</td>
               <td> '".$row["datetime"]."'</td>
              <td> '".$row["ip"]."'</td>
             </tr>
              </form>";
```

Comment: From where did you got `$sb`? ,also where is your query to retrieve that rows?

Comment: From my File , classprove.php , you can to show it here , https://codeshare.io/Gq9byk

Comment: i does it , now to come,  Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMessages() on null in /var/www/html/kommenter_verwalter.php:77\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/kommenter_verwalter.php(115): ClassProveContakt2->tabelle()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/kommenter_verwalter.php on line 77

Comment: It's because your function didn't return anything , try to check like this `var_dump($New->getMessages());`

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMessages()

Comment: try to call that function in your `ClassProveContakt1`and see if give you required rows or not .

Comment: in add on my File, classprove.php,     include 'kommenter_verwalter.php'; and $db = $this ->getMessages();   , what nothing does...

Comment: check : 1 . if your connection to database is there ,2. check if your table name and column names are correct ,3. try to debug each line in your function .

Comment: check 1 and 2 i did it , table name and column are correct https://i.imgur.com/dkoYQpy.png , 3  i to try it , too asked another people....